# Grammatischer Begriff für »alter Hase«, »schiefe Optik« usw.

Tags: word-classes

Es gibt viele Begriffe, die aus einem Adjektiv und einem Substantiv bestehen, die eine eigenständige Bedeutung haben, wie zum Beispiel:

- »alter Hase« = ein erfahrener Mensch
- »schiefe Optik« = Verdacht auf Unregelmäßigkeit

Mich würde interessieren, ob es für diese Adjektiv-Substantiv-Kombinationen einen eigenen grammatikalischen Begriff gibt, und zwar unabhängig davon, ob so eine Kombination eine eigene Bedeutung hat wie in den vorangegangenen Beispielen, oder ob es gewöhnliche Kombinationen sind wie z. B.:

- rotes Auto
- warmes Essen
- dichter Nebel

In Sätzen treten diese Kombinationen häufig als Nominalphrasen oder als Teil davon auf: »**Der alte Hase** weiß, was zu tun ist.« »Karl kaufte sich **ein rotes Auto**.«

Aber eine Nominalphrase ist ein Teil eines Satzes. Mir geht es um eine Bezeichnung, die ohne den Kontext eines umgebenden Satzes auskommt, ähnlich den Bezeichnungen von Wortarten (Substantiv, Pronomen, usw.), die auch einzelne Wörter klassifizieren, ohne dass diese Wörter dazu in einem Satz eingebaut sein müssen.

Die deutsche Sprache enthält eine Menge von Begriffen, die aus mehreren Wörtern bestehen und wie ein Substantiv verwendet werden. Meist sind es Eigennamen (»New York«, »Zweiter Weltkrieg«, »Roter Oktober«), manchmal aber ganz einfache Adjektiv-Substantiv-Kombinationen, die aber nicht den Status eines Eigennamens haben (»tote Hose«, »dringender Tatverdacht«) und trotzdem einen eigenständigen Begriff bilden.

Gibt es für diese »Wort«-Art oder besser: »Begriffs-Art« einen speziellen Namen?

---

**EDIT:**

Grantwalzer hat in seiner sehr guten Antwort bereits die Begriffe »Phraseologismus« und »Wortgruppenlexem« vorgeschlagen. Diese treffen auch auf »alter Hase«, »schiefe Optik« und »tote Hose« zu, nicht aber auf:

- rotes Auto
- warmes Essen
- dichter Nebel
- dringender Tatverdacht

Wobei ich zugebe, dass man da in einigen Fällen geteilter Meinung sein kann, daher will ich versuchen meine Frage genauer zu stellen:

Das Wesentliche ist, dass »Phraseologismus« und »Wortgruppenlexem« **syntaktische** Klassifizierungsbegriffe sind. Die Definitionen beider Begriffe sehen als wesentliches Merkmal vor, dass die Wortgruppen eine *Bedeutung* haben, die über die Bedeutungen der einzelnen Wörter hinausgeht.

Mir geht es aber nicht um Bedeutungen, sondern um eine rein **grammatikalische** Funktion, die von der Bedeutung der Wörter soweit abgekoppelt ist, wie das für grammatische Klassifizierungen eben möglich ist.

Ich will wissen, ob es einen sprachwissenschaftlichen Begriff für die folgenden fett hervorgehobenen Ausdrücke gibt:

> Am **frühen Morgen** lag Nebel im Tal.
>   Walter zog seine **alten Wanderschuhe** an.
>   Der **trockene Tabak** knisterte als er an der **billigen Zigarette** zog.

Comment: Ich hätte jetzt die schiefe Optik eher als verzerrten Blick auf die Realität aufgefasst.

Comment: Suchst Du etwas anderes als Redewendung oder Redensart?

Comment: Ja, ich suche so etwas wie »adverbiertes Substantiv« oder so ähnlich. Eben einen grammatikalischer Taxonomiebegriff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adjektive können als *Attribut* bei einem Substantiv stehen und so das Substantiv unmittelbar näher beschreiben. Man nennt das die *attributive Verwendung* oder den *attributiven Gebrauch* des Adjektivs.

> Sie hat das *blaue* Kleid an.
>   Dort fährt ein *rotes* Auto.
>   Sie hat meinen *neuen* Bleistift.

In verschiedenen Bänden des *Duden* wird die Wortgruppe, die aus dem attributiv gebrauchtem Adjektiv und dem Substantiv besteht, als *attributive Fügung* bezeichnet:

> schöne Jacke
>   blaue Augen

Zu den attributiven Fügungen gehören auch falsche Beziehungen wie

> der vierstöckige Hausbesitzer
>   der geräucherte Fischladen
>   der siebenköpfige Familienvater

Früher war es auch (z. B. in der medizinischen Terminologie) üblich, mit einem Personennamen gebildete mehrgliedrige Bezeichnungen mit einem vom Eigennamen abgeleiteten Adjektiv als attributive Fügung zu bilden:

> basedowsche Krankheit
>   kußmaulsche Atmung
>   gärtnerscher Bazillus
>   ortnersches Zeichen

In *Duden – Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* wird außerdem darauf hingewiesen, dass Wörter wie „Achtelliter“ und „Viertelstunde“ aus attributiven Fügungen wie „drei achtel Liter“ bzw. „in drei viertel Stunden“ zusammengerückt worden sind.

Answer (score 2):

Ergänzend zu dem allgemeinen Begriff der **attribuierten Substantive**: besondere Fügungen wie etwa "schiefe Optik" sind meistens voll- oder teilidiomatische [Phraseologismen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phraseologismus):

> Unter einem Phraseologismus [...] versteht man in der Sprachwissenschaft eine zu einer festen Form verwachsene Folge von Lexemen (Komponenten; Konstituenten), also eine bestimmte Art eines Syntagmas (= grammatische Fügung (Wortverbindung) aus i. d. R. mehreren Wörtern). Die Bedeutung eines solchen sprachlichen Fertigbausteins geht meist über die rein wörtliche Bedeutung ihrer einzelnen Bestandteile hinaus

Die drei Hauptkriterien, die zur Beschreibung von Phraseologismen verwendet werden, sind

- Polylexikalität (mehrere Lexeme/Wörter, check)
- Festigkeit (Stabilität) (Teile können nicht ersetzt oder gar ergänzt werden, check)
- Idiomatizität (Sprichwörtlichkeit, check)

Der Ausdruck "schiefe Optik" ist vollidiomatisch, da beide Bestandteile umgedeutet werden, "alter Hase" kann je nach Sprachgebrauch voll- oder teilidomatisch sein (würde zB jemand eine erfahrene, aber junge Person nicht so bezeichnen - dann würde "alt" auch tatsächlich "alt" bedeuten → Teilidiom).

Eine weitere Einordnungsmöglichkeit bietet die Redensart nach Röhrich:

> Der Sprachwissenschaftler Lutz Röhrich bezeichnet sprichwörtliche Redensarten als Wortgruppen-Lexeme. Sie stehen nicht für sich allein und müssen zur Verwendung innerhalb eines Satzes noch ergänzt werden. Es fehlt ihnen mindestens das Subjekt, wie z. B. bei der Wendung „mit dem Zaunpfahl winken“.

Informationen aus der Wikipedia bezogen.

Comment: Danke! Das hilft mir schon weiter, aber die eigentlich gesuchte Antwort ist es nicht zu 100 %. Denn sowohl »Phraseologismus« als auch »Wortgruppenlexem« haben den Nachteil, dass sie nicht - wie gefordert - grammatikalische Taxonomiebegriffe sind, sondern syntaktische. Die Definition beider Begriffe verlangt nämlich, dass das Adjektiv und das Subjekt eine gemeinsame Bedeutung haben, die über die Bedeutung der Einzelteile hinausgeht. Das ist aber bei den in der Frage genannten Beispielen »rotes Auto«, »warmes Essen« und »dichter Nebel« nicht der Fall.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Achsooo... ich dachte, dass du einen Begriff suchst, der nur "besondere" Fügungen wie "schiefe Optik" beschreibt, also nicht für "gewöhnliche" Fügungen wie "rotes Auto" verwendet werden kann. Verdammt noch einmal, ich habe die Frage schon wieder überflogen: "unabhängig davon, ob so eine Kombination eine eigene Bedeutung hat". Ich lass das Ding ergänzungshalber stehen.........

Answer (score 0):

Ich würde das nicht zu Grammatik tun, sondern zu Stilistik und normalerweise bezeichnet man "ein alter Hase" als Metapher, ein Ersatz für ein Normalwort oder normalen Audruck wie "ein erfahrener Mann" durch ein Sprachbild, das auf einen Vergleich beruht. Hier wird die Erfahrung eines Menschen "hinübergetragen" (Grundidee des griechischen Begriffs Metapher) zu einer Beobachtung der Jäger, die wissen, dass ein alter Hase nicht so leicht zu kriegen ist.

Comment: Klar kann man auch nach einem stilistischen Begriff dafür fragen. Aber das habe ich ausdrücklich nicht gemacht. Ich habe in meinem Frageposting nicht ohne Grund diesen Satz geschrieben: »Mir geht es aber nicht um Bedeutungen, sondern um eine rein grammatikalische Funktion, die von der Bedeutung der Wörter soweit abgekoppelt ist, wie das für grammatische Klassifizierungen eben möglich ist.« Wenn ich nach der physiologischen Funktion der beiden kugelförmigen Organe im Gesicht jedes Menschen frage, will ich als Antwort auch nicht ein Gedicht über die Schönheit der Augen erhalten.